# Как получить цифровой ID пользователя ВКонтакте

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Как получить из ссылки https://vk.com/durov получить https://vk.com/id1, а именно номер страницы, в нашем случае: 1

Answer (score 1):

Есть отличный метод **utils.resolveScreenName** в VK API, определяющий Id по короткому имени. В качестве короткого имени можно использовать как durov, так и id1.

Ответ в данном случае будет такой:

```
{
    "response": {
        "type": "user",
        "object_id": 1
    }
}
```

> Определяет тип объекта (пользователь, сообщество, приложение) и его идентификатор по короткому имени screen_name.

[Подробнее в документации метода](https://vk.com/dev/utils.resolveScreenName)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод users.get. [Подробнее](https://vk.com/dev/users.get)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)